# c# selenium element found but not clicking

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

im building roulette bot, im finding element by xpath i can get its class attiributes etc. but i cant click on it. its always clickable (bot finds ifrime and then finds element and clicks its working but this website gamescreen in iframe>iframe bot can find button but not clicking)

```
            firefox.SwitchTo().Window(firefox.WindowHandles.Last());
            var DBViFrame = firefox.FindElement(By.TagName("iframe"));
            firefox.SwitchTo().Frame(DBViFrame);
            DBViFrame = firefox.FindElement(By.TagName("iframe"));
            firefox.SwitchTo().Frame(DBViFrame);
            var dataEntryButton = firefox.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[name()=\"svg\"]//*[name()=\"g\"]//*[name()=\"rect\"][" + num + "]"));
            
            
         
            dataEntryButton.Click();
```

Comment: Is the element actually being found by your XPATH? try to check if the .size() method do not  returns 0

`dataEntryButton.size() != 0`

Comment: Why you have these line duplicated `var DBViFrame = firefox.FindElement(By.TagName("iframe"));
            firefox.SwitchTo().Frame(DBViFrame);` ? If it's a nested iframe, you should first switch to parent iframe then the child iframe. Also, their locators should be different.

Comment: two iframe is nested can you help me about switching im kinda newbie

Answer (score 0):

Is firefox your WebDriver? If so, maybe try `execute_script` and see if that works?

```
firefox.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", dataEntryButton)
```

Comment: bot can't locate element

Comment: Obviously you need to pass `dataEntryButton` to it... sounds like your issue is in getting the button

Comment: im getting this error now, 'TypeError: arguments[0].click is not a function'